# How can I click only once on the "add text" button and then add several texts in Foxit Reader?

Tags: editing, foxit-reader

I use Foxit Reader to complete a PDF form with the "add text" feature. Current I click on the "add text" button, the add 1 text, then click again on the "add text" button, the add a second text and so on. How can I just click only once on the "add text" button and then add several texts (i.e., click only once on the "add text" button to complete the entire form)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I just click only once on the "add text" button and then add several texts (i.e., click only once on the "add text" button to complete the entire form)?

Currently, it is not possible to click only once on the "add text" button to complete the entire form with Foxit. One has to click on the "add text" button, the add 1 text, then click again on the "add text" button, the add a second text and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Foxit will not work on all forms such as these so those check boxes do not work however to fill a text field you add text then tab to next text no need to keep clicking icons.

[image]